# Send additional (custom) data to m/monit

Tags: monit

I use `monit` (https://mmonit.com/monit/) for system monitoring. 
Also I use my own "backend" instead of `m/monit` and I want to receive additional data from the monit instances.

For example, is it possible to read the data from the file and then send this data together with regular report?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to read from file, but you can send script's result.

Add to `monitrc`

```
check program my-custom-data with path "/path/to/test_mydata.sh"
    if status > 60 then alert . # just example
    group custom-data
```

Bash file example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exit 56
```

and as result you will have this data in your xml

```
<service name="my-custom-data">
            <type>7</type>
            <collected_sec>1564140983</collected_sec>
            <collected_usec>970882</collected_usec>
            <status>0</status>
            <status_hint>0</status_hint>
            <monitor>1</monitor>
            <monitormode>0</monitormode>
            <onreboot>0</onreboot>
            <pendingaction>0</pendingaction>
            <program>
                <started>1564140983</started>
                <status>56</status>
                <output/>
            </program>
        </service>
```